# Install avahi-tools on Centos 9

Tags: linux, centos, avahi

I want to use avahi-browse on Centos 9. I have installed the avahi package but i cannot find the avahi-tools package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a good practice but if finally solved my problem using snap.

```
sudo yum install snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
sudo snap install avahi
```

Answer (score 0):

avahi - Local network service discovery

see the source here:
https://centos.pkgs.org/9-stream/centos-baseos-x86_64/avahi-0.8-11.el9.i686.rpm.html

Comment: That's the source for avahi, not avahi-tools

Comment: @stoney try this:
https://installati.one/centos/7/avahi-tools/